# C/C++ static linking error (LIBCMT.lib)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker, linker-errors, windows-7-x64

I have a C/C++ program x64 which uses a couple of libraries.

The compiler I use: **Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 18.00.31101 for x64**

In the beginning I did have some problems with static/dynamic linking, but I have solved these issues, and I can sucessfully compile my program with MD and MDd flags. Now, I want to get rid of the C runtime library DLLs. I would like to compile my application using MT flags.

The libraries I use: samtools, and zlib ( I use MT flag while generating both of the libraries). At the end, in the linking process I get such an error even though I have used the same configurations for all the compilation process. The error message:

```
LIBCMT.lib(atox.obj) : error LNK2005: atoll already defined in libbam.lib(bam_import.obj)
myApplication.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\BIN\x8
6_amd64\link.exe"' : return code '0x491'
```

commands to generate libraries and linking:

```
    CC=cl.exe
    AR= lib.exe
    CFLAGS= /MT -c
    INCLUDES= -I. -Iwin32

1st library:
    ZLIB: $(OBJS)
        $(AR) objectfiles

    OBJS:
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) sourcefiles

2nd library:
libbam.lib:$(LOBJS)
        $(AR) $(LOBJS) $(BCFOBJS) /out:libbam.lib

    BCFOBJ:
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) sourcefiles

.c.obj:   // LOBJS are generated here
        $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) $< -o $@
```

Command I use to compile my program using the libraries I produced above:

```
    CC=cl.exe
    LINK=link.exe

    FLAGS= -Ox /MT -c
obj1.obj:
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) test.cpp $(INCLUDES)

testMain.obj:
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) testMain.cpp $(INCLUDES)    
testMain.exe: $(OBJ)
        $(LINK) obj1.obj testMain.obj $(LIBS) /OUT:testMain.exe
```

Since the makefiles are quite long, I tried to simplify it a bit, show the flags I use for each library I generate.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us the commad line

Comment: Hi @Kartoch, I have tried to add a couple lines. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem. Apparently, there was a function called atoll() in one of the source files I had for a required library, and while linking statically, the compiler was trying to link the system atoll() function; however, there was one of them already there. I renamed the function in all the source files, and not I can statically compile my application.